# Not getting the correct expectation in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, statistics, probability

I am trying to make the random number generator work, however my expectation is not correct (unless I am fundamentally misunderstanding something).

I have this preset array :

array=[1 0 0]

I proceed to generate a random index between 1 and 3 using the rand() function in MATLAB.

```
index=round(1+2*rand(1,1),0); %generate random index between 1 and 3
```

Subsequently, I am trying to put together an array of entries accessed by the randomly generated index for some number of iterations:

```
answer_array=[] %answer holder
for i = 1:1:iterations %Loop for the set number of iterations
     index=round(1+2*rand(1,1),0);
     answer_array=[answer_array array(index)]
end
```

Then I try to sum the number of 1's in the answer_array and find the ratio of that to the number of iterations

```
temp=0;
for i=1:size(answer_array,2)
    temp=temp+answer_array(1,i) %just sum all array contents as they're either 1 or 0
end

ratio=temp/iterations
```

No matter how large I set my iterations, the ratio converges at 0.24.
Should it not be 0.33? My reasoning is that if I randomly pick the index myself, I have 1/3 chance of getting 1. Thus if I continue picking for a large number of times, my success chance will converge at 1/3?

Comment: Try this expected value is 0.33 : `iterations =1000;a=[1 0 0];r = randi(3,1,iterations);sum(a(r))/iterations
`

Comment: This worked. Thanks! Do you know why the standard rand wasn't working?

Comment: Instead of `round` I think you should use `floor(rand*3)+1` or `ceil(rand*3)`

Comment: Your results are skewed because the range of random values that will result in an index of `1` is `[1.0, 1.5)`. The range of values that will result in an index of `2` is `[1.5, 2.5)`, or a probability of `0.50`. If you check index `3`, you should also see a probability of `0.33`.